# Stack order of images (z-index equvalent)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This is probably a fairly basic question but I haven't managed to find anything on either here or Google. Any help is appreciated.

Is there a property that determines the stack order of objects (images rectangles ect) in a windows phone 7 application. I am adding some from the code behind and some from the xaml. What I'm basically looking for is the z-index property but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the objects in a Canvas, you can use the [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to set the stack order.

Comment: Also ? Also after what? Message order is not fixed here.

Comment: I didn't realize that at first. Edited to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: `Canvas.ZIndex` works not only with Canvas, but with other containers, as well. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474293/windows-phone-7-stack-order-of-images/5474733#5474733).

Answer (score 1):

In the XAML, the default order of items is the reverse of how they appear in the markup (last item in the XAML appears at the top of the stack).

As a test, I wrote the following.

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="Order.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="LayoutTest" Margin="0">
            <Label Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="Added in XAML"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Height = 100d;
            lbl.Width = 100d;
            lbl.MouseLeftButtonUp += rec_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            lbl.Content = "Label number "  + i.ToString();
            lbl.Background = Brushes.White;
            lbl.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

            LayoutTest.Children.Add(lbl);
        }
    }

    void rec_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Label obj = sender as Label;
        if (null == obj) return;
        obj.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

The result was that items added in XAML appear at the bottom of the stack, in the order described above.  Items added in code appear above them, and their order is dictated by the order they were added - first item added is at the bottom of the particular order, getting higher up the stack as they are added.

So, at the "bottom" of the pile is the label
"Added in XAML", followed by
"Label number 0",
"Label number 1",
... up to ...
"Label number 9" being the topmost, immediately visible item.

Bother! I've just spent 10 minutes proving the wrong thing. ;)  Roy C's answer below is probably what you were looking for, but with a bit of luck, this answer will be of some use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28VS.95%29.aspx) attached property. It should work with all layout containers, not just Canvas.

In the big .NET there's actually a [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx), which makes more sense, but [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28VS.95%29.aspx) seems to work just fine in WP7.